# Did Rama know that he was Avatar of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, shiva-purana

[This](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga50/yuddha_50_frame.htm)  chapter of Ramayana narrates the meeting of Garuda with Rama.

> न च कौतूहलं कार्यं सखित्वं प्रति काङ्क्षिणा ।
>
> कृतकर्मा रणे वीर सखित्वं प्रतिवेत्स्यसि ॥६-५०-५७
>
> "O, hero! You need not be so curious to know the casue of my
>   friendship. You will know of it, once you have accomplished success in
>   battle."

This implies Rama was not aware of his avatar.This might be because Ravana could only killed by human.

But [this](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/20655/7/Part1_Chapter5_321-400p.pdf) chapter from Rudra Samhita Section of Shiva Purana (Pg 388) narrates story of Sati meeting Rama.

> 48. On seeing Sati in guise of Sita, Rama the scion of Raghu's race repeated the name Shiva, realized the truth and laughed. He bowed to
>       her and said
> 49. "O Sati,Obeisance to you. Where has Shiva gone? Please tell me affably.How is that you come here alone without your husband?"
> 50. "O goddess Sati, Why have you cast off your own form and assumed this guise? Take pity on me and tell me the reason thereof ".
> 51. On hearing the words of Rama,Sati was stunned.Remembering Siva's words and realizing the truth of same she felt ashamed.

This implies Rama was aware of His avatar.

Also [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3079/3500) answer says

> Yoga Vashishtha, the text which states conversations between
>   Vashistha, a rig vedic teacher, and various Gods and Kakbhushubdi, a
>   creature which stands outside of normal time and sees all. It recounts
>   the cyclical nature of time, where Kakabhushundi has seen Ramayan 11
>   times with different outcomes and seen Mahabharat 16 times with
>   different results, but, after seeing Daksha Yagya twice, he did not
>   either care to see it again or saw no point to seeing any more, as it
>   ended the same way each time.

It says Ramayana happened 11 times and outputs were different each time. So we can presume Rama who met Sati to be Rama of earlier yugas, not Rama of 24th Treta Yuga. But the serial [Devon Ke Dev Mahadev](http://www.hotstar.com/tv/devon-ke-dev-mahadev/12/lord-shiva-fumes-at-sati/1000000334) says they met Rama by travelling to future. So, according to this serial, they went from Swayambhuva Manvantara of Pitri Kalpa to 24th Treta Yuga of Vaivastara Manvantara of Swetha Varaha Kalpa.

- If we assume that Rama,who met Sati,was aware of His avatar and Rama
  of 24th Treta Yuga was not aware of his avatar, then why it was
  written in Shiva Purana **Rama, scion of Raghu's race**.?
- Does that mean Rama will always take birth in Raghu's Race?
- Or was chapter of Shiva Purana misinterpreted?

Without considering above questions,

- Did Rama of 24th Treta Yuga know that he was Avatar of Vishnu?

Comment: It is always the same parabrahma who takes birth as Rama. Rama is always born into ikshvaku dynasty and is always and forever with Sita. Minor changes may occur in different kalpas but essential ramayana remains the same.

Comment: Always Ikshvaku? why?

Comment: it will be better if we can just consider Ramayana for lord rama which itself is consisting of 24000 verses.@TheDestroyer

Comment: @RakeshJoshi You mean we have to consider only Ramayana of 24k verses not Puranas ?

Comment: If rama claimed any such things then why would valmiki not mention it? for Rama the best authority is Ramayana and NOT Puranas.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Ok. We already discussed our stands on Puranas. Let's not discuss that again.

Comment: Yes, For the Ramayana, best authority is the Valmiki Ramayana since it is for the latest Rama Avatar.

Answer (score 9):

At the end of Ramayana war, when Brahma & Devas extol him as Supreme, Rama says '

> abravittridashashreShThaan raamo dharmabhR^itaaM varaH |
>   **AtmAnam mAnusham manye rAmam daSarathAtmajam** VR 6.117.11
>
> Rama, the lord of creation, who was born in Raghu dynasty and the foremost one among protectors of righteousness, spoke to those god-chiefs as follows: **I consider myself as a human, Rama, the son of Dasharatha**

Will any human say that he considers himself human ? What other choice would he have ?

Rama is one of the avatars of Vishnu. Avataranam means to descend. A person who is in a high throne descends to low places to help people. Rama and Vishnu are not two separate entities, they are just different names of same God. So there is no question of whether one is aware of other.

But Rama, in order to play the role of a man convincingly, tries his best not to display any God-like qualities, or take help from Devas/Brahma etc.

Answer (score 5):

Sri Rama was undoubtedly aware of his divinity. In the Ramcharitmanas written by Valmiki incarnate Tulsidas, Rama is well aware of Ravana's plan of abducting Sita and orders Her to remain in fire who in turn leaves behind her shadow (who is abducted by Ravana later) until He vanquishes Ravana:

> When Lakshmana had gone to the woods to gather roots, fruits and bulbs, Sri Rama, the very incarnation of compassion and joy, spoke with a smile to Janaka's
>   Daughter:
>
> Listen, my darling, who have been staunch in the holy vow of fidelity to me and
>   are so virtuous in conduct: **I am going to act a lovely human part. Abide in fire until I have
>   completed the destruction of the demons. No sooner had Sri Rama told Her everything in detail than She impressed the image of the Lord's feet on Her heart and entered into
>   the fire, leaving with Him only of a shadow of Hers, though precisely of the same appearance and the same amiable and gentle disposition. Lakshmana too did not know the secret of what the Lord had done behind the curtain.** The ten-headed Ravana approached Marica and bowed his head to him, selfish and vile as he was. The meekness of a mean creature is a source of great trouble like the bending of a goad,
>   bow, snake or cat. The sugar cooted speech of a villain is as alarming, Bhavani (Parvati), as the flowers that blossom out of season. (**Ramcharitmanas, Aranya Kanda, Doha 23, Chopai 1-4**)

Answer (score 2):

I think Rama was verily aware of His divine status. Here is my reason, then I'll quote. Firstly there are many stories present in Valmiki Ramayana which are absent in other Ramayanas. Like the Shabari story, Rama, if He was a humble human wouldn't have accepted Shabari's divine bhakti as a God treats His devotees. He would have been humble enough to point out that He's human, knowing very well that Shabari was a siddha. He points out the 9 ways of Bhakti, which very subtly exposes that Rama was well aware of His divinity.

Ahalya on the other hand. When Vishwamitra asked Rama to keep His foot and liberate Ahalya, Rama didn't show humane humility in accepting that He wasn't God Himself. Instead He readily liberates Ahalya from her suffering. This is mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayana, so not quoting it here.

The Adhyatma Ramayana:

Shabari:

> Such pure devotion is expressed in nine ways. First is satsang or
>   association with love-intoxicated devotees and righteous people. The
>   second is to develop a taste for hearing *My* nectar-like stories. The
>   third is service to the guru (...) Fourth is to sing *My* kirtan
>   (communal chorus) (...) Japa or repetition of *My Holy name and
>   chanting My bhajans* are the fifth expression (...) To follow
>   scriptural injunctions always, to practice control of the senses,
>   nobility of character and selfless service, these are expressions of
>   the sixth mode of bhakti. Seeing *Me manifested everywhere in this
>   world and worshipping My saints more than myself* is the seventh mode
>   of bhakti. To find no fault with anyone and to be contented with one's
>   lot is the eighth mode of bhakti. Unreserved surrender with total
>   faith in *My* strength is the ninth and highest stage. Shabari, anyone
>   who practices one of these nine modes of *My bhakti pleases Me most and
>   reaches Me without fail.* That which is most difficult for the greatest
>   yogis was easily attained by you, Shabari, because of your sincere
>   devotion.

Comment: I thought you didn't read the Adhyatma Ramayana?

Comment: I quoted this from my pdf. I haven't gone beyond Ayodhya Kanda.

Answer (score 2):

No, Rama despite being a Purna-Avataara,did not know His Swarupa according to the Brahmavaivarta-Purana (Chapter 116).He forgot His true self because of curse of Brahmaa:

> Sarve chamshakalaa pungshah Krishnastu bhagavan svayam/**Paripurnatamo Ramo brahma-shaapaat sva-bismritah**// (Reference: Pranava Pema Pijusha Bhashya of Gita, Sitaramdas Omkarnath, Mahamilan Math, vol 2, page 49)

Answer (score 2):

**सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।**
Get clear view of Shlokā;
आत्मानं **मानुषं** मन्ये रामं दशरथात्मजम् || (६-११७-११)
Many of us some times get easily confused with this shlokā, as we think the word ***maanuSham ***here means human. But this is not true, earlier (https://www.quora.com/Did-Shri-Ram-really-say-that-he-is-a-human-being/answer/Ram-Rasik-2) I have already explained it and you guys have given a very good response in that but this time let's see same Shlokā with a quite different meaning.
The actual meaning of Manushya is successors of Manu (one who has appeared in Manu Dynasty= मनु के वंश में प्रकट हैं इसीलिए मनुष्य कहे जाते हैं)
And he is the same Manu who has established Ayodhyā on earth as said in Vedāvatāar Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmayan 1.5.6;
अयोध्या नाम नगरी तत्रऽऽसीत् लोकविश्रुता।
मनुना मानवेन्द्रेण या पुरी निर्मिता स्वयम्॥
A world-renowned city is there in that kingdom, which is personally built by Manu, the foremost ruler of mankind.
And Lord Śrī Rām has appeared in same Manu Dynasty. So actually Shri Ram in aatmaanam **maanuSham** manye *raamam* *dasharathaatmajam*** **(6.117.21) is saying that,** “In dynasty of Manu (मनुवंश= मनुष्य) I recognise myself as a son of Dasarātha".**
Again repeating, Śrī Ram has never said he is Manushya rather he has siad, I recognise myself as a son of Dasarātha in the dynasty of Manu. (मनु वंश में मैं दशरथ नंदन राम हूं)
Matlb Śrī Brahmā ji is saying to Shri Ram लोकानामादिकर्ता स्वयं प्रभुः two Times in that same sarg (117) which means You are alone Swāyam Bhagwān (free from everyone, nobody is above you) as this also confirms the Vedās saying;
प्रतियोगिविनिर्मुक्तब्रह्मविद्यैकगोचरम् ।
अखण्डनिर्विकल्पं तद्रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥
I worship the lotus feet of Lord Śrī Rāmachandrā, who has no alternative, i e. he is *Nirvikālp*, when Brahmavidya is said, then only he is visible. And who is free from all kinds of competition (because no one can stand along him).
(Krishna Yajurveda Sarasvati-rahasya Upanishad 1.1)
So kindly do not fall in the trap of these modern intellectuals who are ready to prove their demonic mindset. And please read that sarg (117) of Yuddha Kand. So that no may beguile you in this context. Lord of Sāket Śrī Rām is not an avatar of anyone he is swayam Paratpār Par-Brahmā as confirmed by Vedās ITSELF;

> एतेषु चैव सर्वेषु तत्त्वं च ब्रह्म तारकम् ।
> राम एव परं ब्रह्म राम एव परं तपः ।।
> राम एव परं तत्त्वं श्रीरामो ब्रह्म तारकम् ।।
> वायुत्रेणोक्तास्ते योगीन्द्रा ऋषयो विष्णुभक्ता हनूमन्तं पप्रच्छुः रामस्याङ्गानि नो ब्रूहीति ।
> वायुपुत्रं विघ्नेशं वाणीं दुर्गां क्षेत्रपालकं सूर्यं चन्द्रं नारायणं नारसिंहं वायुदेवं वाराहं तत्सर्वान्त्समात्रान्त्सीतं लक्ष्मणं शत्रुघ्नं भरतं विभीषणं सुग्रीवमङ्गदं जाम्बवन्तं प्रणवमेतानि रामस्याङ्गानि जानीथाः ।
> **(Yajurvedā Shäkhayam RāmRahāshyopanishād 1.6/7½)**
> In all the scriptures like Vedās, the supreme principle is 'Tāraka Rāma' in the form of Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is alnoe Supreme Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is alone highest Tapa. Śrī Rāma is alone highest Tattva. Śrī Rāma is alone Taraka Brahma. Hanumān Ji preached to the devotee of Śrī Hāri Vīshnu and other Rishis "I myself, Śrī Ganēshā, Goddess Saraswati, Goddess Durgā, All the Guardian (Khetra Pāl), Sun (Suryā), Moon, **Lord Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, Lord Naräsimha, Lord Vāsudev (Śrī Krishnā), Lord Vāraha etc.** all are the **mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma.** Lakshmāna, Shātrughna, Bharata, Vibhishana, Sugriva, Angad, Jambavant and Pranav (Om ॐ) are also mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma.
> Again from Vedās ITSELF;
> ब्रह्मादिपञ्चब्रह्माणो यत्र विश्रान्तिमाप्नुयुः ।
> तदखण्डसुखाकारं रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥
> **(Krishna Yajurvedā Shäkhayam Pānch Brahmõpanishād 1.1)**
> I worship the lotus feet of Lord Śrī Rāmachandrā, the cause of eternal bliss, where the five Brahmas (Shri Shiva, Shri Hāri Vīshnu, Shri Ganesha, Bhagwati Durga and Shri Surya) along with Brahma etc. always find rest (ashraya).
> And above all Vedsaar Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas says;
> रामु काम सत कोटि सुभग तन । दुर्गा कोटि अमित अरि मर्दन ॥
> सक्र कोटि सत सरिस बिलासा । नभ सत कोटि अमित अवकासा ॥
> सारद कोटि अमित चतुराई । बिधि सत कोटि सृष्टि निपुनाई ॥
> बिष्नु कोटि सम पालन कर्ता । रुद्र कोटि सत सम संहर्ता ॥
> **(ŚrīRāmacaritamānasa 7.92.3/5)**
> Śrī Rāma's body possesses the charm of a myriad Cupids. He is as inexorable in crushing the enemy as countless millions of Durgās. He enjoys the luxury of a myriad Indra-s and is immeasurable in expanse as a myriad firmaments. He is as sharp as countless millions of Saraswatis-s and possesses the creative skill of a myriad Brahmā-s. Again, He is as good a preserver as billions of Vishṇu-s and as thorough a destroyer as billions of Rudra-s.

**Please Chant SitaRam SitaRam SitaRam**
Hail to Nityä Rasēshwar Rasēshwari ❤️
Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya

Answer (score 0):

Rama did not know about his divinity. But this doesn't make him less divine. He is God in a human frame.

**Some of instances**

- When he meets bharadwaj muni during his vanvas - sage bharadwaj prays
  to him saying he is master ans superior of all beings.Lord ram
  replies with folded hands that o great sage i only know that i am son
  of dasratha and am here to fulfill my duties.else i know nothing.
- When lord viswamitra praises him for killing demoness tadka and
  liberating ahilya quoting that no normal being could have
  accomplished this feat - sri ram politely neglects this and says its
  all ur blessing guru viswamitra.
- When garud dev emancipates sri ram and laxman from nagpaash of
  meghnad he prays to lord ram that its his duty to serve him and there
  relation of sevak swami has existed for countless yugas. Hearing this
  sri ram asks ignorantly about what relation it is and i have never
  seen you before.Hearing this sri garud dev as quotes in
  ramcharitmanas replies " jab nij dham laut prabhu aihon..sevak ko
  prabhu parichay paihon...kaah puchat ho parichay swami...tum sab
  janat antaryami". This explains that although lord ram was divine and
  almighty but in his manujroop he appeared to be ignorant and acted in
  humanly ways.
- When after killing ravana all divas praise him he politely prays to all of them ignoring his superhuman status.
- Last instance is when lord bramha sends yamraj to inform lord ram
  that all deeds which he had to furnish on earth are done and its time
  for his return...he agains partially acts in an ignorant manner.

**Hence we can say that lord ram acted in human ways and never showed any of his almighty forms or divine acts like lord krishna during his lifetime.**

Comment: Thanks you! But what do you say about Shiva Purana chapter? BTW, Please cite sources.  Here is [Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/)

Comment: @The Des: The person who answered has not quoted any scriptural reference . Not only for this question but for many others also. Can he be advised on this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Valmiki Ramayana, Lord Rama didn't know about himself as Lord Vishnu.

**Book VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War. Chapter [Sarga] 117.:**

> *ityukto lokapaalaistaiH svaamii lokasya raaghavaH || 6-117-10
> abravittridashashreShThaan raamo dharmabhR^itaaM varaH |*
>
> *Hearing the words of those guardians of the world, Rama, the lord of creation, who was born in Raghu dynasty and the foremost one among protectors of righteousness, spoke to those god-chiefs as follows.:*
>
> *aatmaanaM maanuShaM manye raamaM dasharathaatmajam || 6-117-11
> so.ahaM yasya yatashchaahaM bhagavaMstadbraviitu me |*
>
> *"**I think of myself to be a human being, by name Rama, the son of Dasaratha. You, as a gracious Divinity, tell me that which I as such really am like this.**"*

There are other instances also, anyways according to Ramcharitmanas of Sri Tulsidas Goswami Ji he knew about himself so prayed to Lord Agni and thus the story of Chaya Sita.

So, it's upto people to believe what they want and from which text.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..