# Did Ikshvaku Rama rule Ayodhya or Vishnu avatara Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama, avatars

As we know the purpose of Rama avatara was to liberate Ravana, and for this purpose Vishnu had to forget his divinity. But in the Yuddha Kanda, after the Agni Pariksha, all the devas headed by Brahma arrive and praise Rama reminding him of his Divinity. They tell him that he is Vishnu and Sita is Lakshmi. You can read the praises of Brahma [here](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddha_117_frame.htm)

After this Rama becomes the King of Ayodhya. So now did Rama rule with the knowledge that he was Vishnu or did he forget it again? That is did Vishnu sit on the throne of Ayodhya or Dasaratha's son?

And similarly was Sita sent to the forest where she lamented her fate to Lakshmana - or did Mahalakshmi lament to Anantadeva?

Comment: See my question [Did Rama know that he was Avatar of Lord Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9188/3500)

Comment: @Anil Yes but my question is after the time period of the answer for that.

Comment: From this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sribhashyam_Appalacharyulu): "He [Sribhashyam Appalacharyulu] has proved that Rama was never conscious of his divine identity unto six kandas of the epic and he had emerged as 'Narayana' in the seventh kanda only - this 'Narayana Tatva' he calls the 'divine idea'."

Comment: @sv. So since he emerges as Narayana in Uttara Kanda dies it mean that Vishnu was the king of Ayodhya?

Answer (score -1):

In Hinduism, God/deities born as humans to end worldly suffering. For this, they also suffer like us such as Ram, Siya, Lakhan, suffered. They may be knowing that they are deities/god like Ram new that but never displayed it selfly whereas sometimes they may not be knowing like Balram, elder bro of Krishna. So, the conditions may vary...

Comment: That is true in Krsna's case. But Rama avatara was different.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Rama came for very different reasons.