# Why wouldn't Sita go back to Mithila after she was abandoned by Shri Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita

After Sita was exiled by Rama,why didn't she go back to Mithila?
Isn't she Mithila's princess?Even if she didn't go, why couldn't Janaka arrange for his daughter Janaki's protection in the jungle?

Comment: Sita was a pativrata that is she strictly followed her husband's words.
Rama had her to vanavas. she followed that and went to the forest rather than going to mithila.

Answer (score -1):

The episode of abandoning of Sita by Sri Rama appears in Uttara Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana.

UTTARA KANDA is a PRAKSHIPTA/an interpolated story - an insertion made at a later date.  [Ramayana ends with the coronation of Sri Rama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8999/3869) as the King of Ayodhya.

[A 6th Century version of Ramayana](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/kolkata/6th-century-Ramayana-found-in-Kolkata-stuns-scholars/articleshow/50227724.cms) was found in a library of Kolkata.  According to this version, there are just five kandas (sections) instead of the accepted seven. There is no Bala kanda or Uttara kanda.

As the episode of banishment of Sita finds place in this interpolated Uttara Kanda, further queries like whether Sri Rama was justified in banishing Sita or Why did not Sita go back to Mithila, etc, may not arise.

Comment: The linked article says "Before long, they realized it was a 6th-century version with many interpolations", so we can't draw any hard conclusions from it.

Comment: I agree. However,  it was also mentioned that it did not contain Uttara kana. @sv.