# Rama's family values as interpreted by devotees

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, lakshmana

Rama is considered the perfect husband. He is also well known for the strong brotherly bond with lakshmana.

However, by the end of Ramayana, Rama is shown to abandon both sita and lakshmana for various reasons. So,

- Why is Rama still strongly associated with family bonds?
- Is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood. Lord Rāma is known as Maryada Purushottama which means the best of men or the Supreme Purusa (personality), not as a 'perfect family man'.

Take the two incidents, exile of [Sita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/276/did-lord-rama-exile-maa-sita) and [Lakshmana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/why-did-lord-rama-and-lakshman-separate). Both of these incidents happened after Lord Rama becoming the ruler of Kingdom Ayodhya. The dharma of a king is to lead his people in the path of Dharma. King Rama was forced to exile Sita(and that was not husband Rama) for keeping the Dharma. The same Dharma exiled Lakshmana(and it was not brother Rama).

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama),

> As a person, Rama personifies the characteristics of an ideal person (purushottama)[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama)[83] who is to be emulated. He had within him all the desirable virtues that any individual would seek to aspire, and he fulfils all his moral obligations (maryada). Rama's purity and piety in his intentions and actions inspires affection and devotion for him from a variety of characters from different backgrounds. For example, he gave up his rightful claim to the throne, and agreed to go into exile for fourteen years, to fulfill the vow that his father had given to Kaikeyi, one of King Dashratha's wives. This is in spite of the fact that Kaikeyi's son, Bharat, begged him to return to Ayodhya and said that he did not want to rule in place of Rama. But Rama considered his dharma as a son above that of his own birthright and his life's ambition. For such supreme sacrifices, and many other qualities, Rama is considered a maryada purushottama(the best of upholders of Dharma).

Also while mentioning family you forgot to mention about the perfect son.

> Some of his ideals are as follows:
>
> 1. At the time when it was normal for kings to have more than one wife, Rama gave the ideal of having a single wife. After Sita was banished, he was doing penance with a gold statue of Sita. In Balakanda of Valmiki Ramayana it is written that Rama and Sita resided in each other's heart.
> 2. **Rama always followed his promise at any cost**. In fact, he went to forest to make his **father's promise** to Kaikeyi true. Another instance was when, he had promised the Spirit of Time that during their conversation, if anyone was to intrude, Rama would have pronounce an instant death sentence upon the individual. They were intruded upon by his beloved younger brother Lakshmana, and to keep his part of the promise, pronounced the death sentence. There are many examples of Rama's promises which he kept. Most important are the promise to sages to save their lives from Rakshasas, getting back Sugreeva's kingdom, making Vibhishana the king of Lanka.

Most of these qualities make a perfect family man too. So one of my statement needed to be corrected, he was a perfect family man too. Your doubts can be cleared by reading the Ramayana. It's just explaining the qualities of Lord Rama and how should one live for Dharma.

Sri Rāma - in the words of Swami Vivekananda - is "the embodiment of truth, of morality, the ideal son, the ideal husband, and above all, the ideal king."

Vivekanada quoted it in the correct order. Son,husband and then the ideal king.

Answer (score 2):

First, family bonds include bonds with parents, brothers, sisters, in-laws, children, other relatives. Dharma towards each bond  is different and so is dharma towards a particular person in different circumstances. For example, it is just as important a dharma to love and defend your child as it is to discipline them when they stray. Rama lived by all dharmas towards all.

Secondly, if you examine the Ramayana closely, you will notice Rama comes across as a sensitive, loyal, selfless  and brave husband and lover. He dissuades Sita from accompanying him to the forests. She scolds him roundly and he does not retaliate because he is no old fashioned chauvinist. He defends her against all danger starting with Viradha. He states that he cannot bear the thought of separation from her .   He was not to be tempted by other women including surpanakha. He strove to fulfill his wife's wishes and went after the fantastic golden deer. He suffered severe pangs of separation after Sita was kidnapped. He waged war to save her. For some trivia, In the beginning of the yuddha Kanda, there is an episode where he is lying flat on his back remembering his wife as he looks at the moon. This is a tender moment which inspired kalidasa to compose meghasandesam.

All the above are testimony to Rama's superiority as a  husband. Now coming to abandoning Sita towards the end of their avatar, the previous responder has already highlighted raja dharma(ethics of an ideal king ). He remained loyal to her even after the incident.